# How to query all rows where a given column matches at least all the values in a given array with PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, where-clause, relational-division

The request below:

```
SELECT foos.id,bars.name
FROM foos
JOIN bar_foo ON (bar_foo.foo_id = id )
JOIN bars ON (bars.id = bar_foo.bar_id )
```

returns a list like this:

```
id | name
---+-----
 1 | a
 1 | b
 2 | a
 2 | y
 2 | z
 3 | a
 3 | b
 3 | c
 3 | d
```

How to get the ids for which `id` must have at least `a` and `b`, and more generally the content of a given array ?

From the example above, I would get:

```
id | name
---+-----
 1 | a
 1 | b
 3 | a
 3 | b
 3 | c
 3 | d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two values, you can use windowing boolean aggregation:

```
select *
from (
    select f.id, b.name, 
        bool_or(b.name = 'a') over(partition by id) has_a,
        bool_or(b.name = 'b') over(partition by id) has_b
    from foos f
    join bar_foo bf on bf.foo_id = f.id
    join bars b on b.id = bf.bar_id
) t
where has_a and has_b
```

A more generic approach uses array aggregation:

```
select *
from (
    select f.id, b.name, 
        array_agg(b.name) over(partition by id) arr_names
    from foos f
    join bar_foo bf on bf.foo_id = f.id
    join bars b on b.id = bf.bar_id
) t
where arr_names @> array['a', 'b']
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting `ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying[] @> text[]`

Comment: @DevonDahon: then you need to cast: `where arr_names::text[] @> array['a', 'b']`